# Installing a Spark Cluster, problems with Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, shark-sql

I am trying to get a Spark/Shark cluster up but keep running into the same problem. 
I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/amplab/shark/wiki/Running-Shark-on-a-Cluster and addressed Hive as stated.

I think that the Shark Driver is picking up another version of Hadoop jars but am unsure why.

Here are the details, any help would be great.

Spark/Shark 0.9.0

Apache Hadoop 2.3.0

Amplabs Hive 0.11

Scala 2.10.3

Java 7

I have everything install but I get some deprecation **warnings** and then an exception:

14/03/14 11:24:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive

14/03/14 11:24:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1072)
    at shark.memstore2.TableRecovery$.reloadRdds(TableRecovery.scala:49)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.<init>(SharkCliDriver.scala:275)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:162)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1070)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1137)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
```

Comment: Please provide your hive-env.sh, hive-site.xml, spark-env.sh, shark-env.sh and HADOOP_CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and I think it's caused by incompatible versions of hadoop/hive and spark/shark.

You need to either:

- Remove hadoop-core-1.0.x.jar from `shark/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/`
- When building shark, explicitly set `SHARK_HADOOP_VERSION` as follows:

  ```
  cd shark;
  SHARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0 ./sbt/sbt clean
  SHARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0 ./sbt/sbt package
  ```

The second method solved other issues for me as well. You can also see this topic for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shark-users/lTNPcxHJiOQ/EqzyByZrzQMJ